# Trying to add two ints,in x86, however when i add I get garbage instead of a value. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .rodata
ask1 db "Enter an integer: ", 0
ask2 db "Enter another Int: ",0
num_format db "%ld",0

section .text
global main
;c-style stuff
extern printf, scanf


main:
    ;getting it ready
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp
    sub  rsp, 16
    push rbx
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    push r15
    pushfq

    ;promt user for first int
    mov  rdi, dword ask1
    xor  rax, rax
    call printf
    ;read first int
    lea  rsi, [rbp-8]
    ;initialize location of first int
    mov  rdi, dword num_format
    xor  rax, rax
    call scanf

    ;read second number
    mov  rdi, dword ask2
    xor  rax, rax
    call printf
    ;read second #
    lea  rsi, [rbp-16]
    mov  rdi, dword num_format
    xor  rax, rax
    call scanf
    ; add two numbers together - put sum in RCX
    xor   rbx, rbx      ; effectively zero out rbx 
    xor   rcx, rbx      ; effectively zero out rcx 
    mov   rcx, [rbp-16] ; load rcx with value 16 bytes from base ptr 
    mov   rbx, [rbp-8]  ; load rbx with value 8 bytes from base ptr 
    add   rcx, rbx      ; add num1 + num2 - store in rcx 

    jmp exit

exit:
    call printf
    popfq
    pop r15 
    pop r14 
    pop r13 
    pop r12 
    pop rbx 
    add rsp, 16
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I've formatted your code for you (you could do that the next time yourself), and added the "assembly" tag.

Comment: Is it that the value in `rcx` after the `add` isn't the sum of what was in `rcx` and `rbx`, or that it had the right value but didn't get printed properly?

Comment: yes I get garbage a string of unreadable chars

Comment: Your last `printf` needs arguments (EAX, ESI, EDI...) like the other `printf`s.

Comment: thanks rkhb, im going to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last `call printf` needs arguments (EAX, format string, ...).

Add a line to `.rodata`:

```
printf_format db "%lld",0        ; lld: 64-bit integer
```

and change

```
...
exit:
    call printf
...
```

to

```
...
exit:
    mov rsi, rcx
    mov rdi, printf_format
    xor eax, eax
    call printf
...
```

BTW: You don't need the bunch of `pop`s and `add rsp...` at the end of the main procedure. A simple `leave` is enough to adjust the stack.

Comment: @voltron: I made a mistake in the format string. Please take a look at my updated answer.