# Segmentation Fault call printf

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, x86-64, libc

```
.text
    .global main
main:
  pushq $10
  popq %rdx
  movq $formatString, %rdi
  call printf
    mov $0,%rax
    ret
.data
 formatString:
.string "%d\n"
```

This code gives me a segmentation fault.
It's very simple. Push 10 onto the stack. Pop 10 off the stack and put it into rdx. Move my formatString to rdi. Call printf. That's it.

Why is it giving me a segmentation fault?

Thanks!

Comment: You know you can `mov $10, %edx`, right?  Now this is just a duplicate of the many forgot-to-zero-rax before calling a var-args function question.  I linked one of those as a possible duplicate on your previous question.  `push`ing a dummy register is a useful way to align the stack before a `call`, in a function that doesn't otherwise need to reserve any space.  Also, read the ABI docs.  The 2nd arg doesn't go in `%rdx`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to add two ints,in x86, however when i add I get garbage instead of a value. what am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706080/trying-to-add-two-ints-in-x86-however-when-i-add-i-get-garbage-instead-of-a-val)

Comment: The stack also needs to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary, _RAX_ needs to be zero in this case because you are using no vector registers.

Answer (score 1):

This code could work:

```
.text
    .global main
main:
  add $-8, %rsp             # Stack is misaligned by 8 after call to main
                            # Subtract 8 to align it on 16-byte boundary
  xor %rax, %rax            # RAX = 0 since no vector registers used for calling printf 
                            # This is important for functions that take variable 
                            # number of arguments
  movq $formatString, %rdi  # First parameter (format) in RDI
  movq $10, %rsi            # second parameter in RSI not RDX
  call printf

  add $8, %rsp              # Restore stack to proper state
  ret

.data
 formatString:
.string "%ld\n"             # If printing longs use %ld
```

Rather than `add $-8, %rsp` and `add $8, %rsp` for stack alignment you could use anything that adjusts the stack by 8 bytes. `push %rbx` and `pop %rbx` would have worked as well.

Alternatively you could replace:

```
 movq $formatString, %rdi  # First parameter (format) in RDI
```

With:

```
leaq formatString(%rip), %rdi
```

The latter uses RIP-relative addressing rather than absolute.

More information on the Linux 64-bit System V ABI can be found in this [document](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).